# How to handle API with a big json file?

Tags: database, api, database-design, server

Let's assume I have a rather big (100mb - 250k json objects of similar schema) json file with data. My goal is to store this data on a server and provide API calls for it. The problem is that if I dump it into RAM, it takes more than 1GB of memory, which is obviously too much. The question is - What is the best way to store that data on a server? Where should I start?

Comment: Can you parse the json file contents on first API call and then cache that into a variable, and keep your data stored in the json file like you already have it?

Comment: I would need to store it in RAM anyways, otherwise the API will be slow.